# Calculate Network Time Protocol (offset) in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ntp

I would like to calculate NTP offset in Objective-C. Are there any APIs available to accomplish the same in objective-C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [the ios-ntp project](http://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/); hopefully you'll be able to see how the author of the project is accessing the NTP servers.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have already checked this links but it seems that there is some problem in terms of checking out its source code through SVN

Comment: @sandy - I checked it out with the following `svn` command: `svn checkout http://ios-ntp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ios-ntp-read-only`  You can also see the individual files by going to the site and clicking Source-->browse-->svn-->trunk-->classes.